# Why does Dumbledore act as if Ariana is totally gone, even though she has a portrait?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

As is made most clear in chapter 35 of *Deathly Hallows*, Albus wants to talk to Ariana again. He particularly wanted the resurrection stone for this purpose. Why are there no signs that he ever acts on or acknowledges the fact that she has a portrait? Judging by how his own portrait acts in chapters 33 and 36, her portrait should've been enough for him to ask questions or beg forgiveness.

Comment: Dumbledore talked/gave memories to his portrait, as did most of the other headmasters. which made those portraits unique as they really had memories and parts of personalities. while ariana's portrait was most likely created posthumously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Albus Dumbledore had a particularly realistic painting because he was a powerful wizard and his portrait was painted well before his death, giving him time to talk with it and train it to be more like him.

As stated by [Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/how-do-magical-portraits-actually-work):

> According to J.K. Rowling, the more powerful you are, the more ‘real’ your portrait can be, and if you sit down with your portrait and spend more time with it, the more accurate a portrayal of yourself it will hold. This is why Albus Dumbledore’s portrait is so lifelike, while his Chocolate Frog card, which also holds his image, is more of a fleeting snapshot – which is still sentient in a smaller way.

In contrast, Ariana had no ability to control magic, and it’s unlikely that she spent much time with her painting, if it wasn’t posthumous — after all, her death was unexpected and (at least in the movies) her painting appears to depict her at an time near her death. Her painting is likely more like a “fleeting snapshot” of what she was really like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think portraits are that accurate to the person they depict, most likely it is only one facet of their personality like with Sir Cadogan being a ridiculous knight all the time, furthermore Arianna was mentally ill by the time of her death and a portrait of her might now be able to understand something like her own death well enough to forgive someone like a living person (even if mentally ill) might be able to do.